# Calls for constructors and destructors do not match the number of objects created

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

```
class Line
{
public:
    int getLength(void);
    Line(int len);         // simple constructor
    Line(const Line &obj); // copy constructor
    ~Line();               // destructor

private:
    int *ptr;
};
```

```
// Member functions definitions including constructor
Line::Line(int len)
{
    cout << "Normal constructor allocating ptr" << endl;

    // allocate memory for the pointer;
    ptr = new int;
    *ptr = len;
}

Line::Line(const Line &obj)
{
    cout << "Copy constructor allocating ptr." << endl;
    ptr = new int;
    *ptr = *obj.ptr; // copy the value
}

Line::~Line(void)
{
    cout << "Freeing memory!" << endl;
    delete ptr;
}

int Line::getLength(void)
{
    return *ptr;
}

void display(Line obj)
{
    cout << "Length of line : " << obj.getLength() << endl;
}
```

```
// Main function for the program
int main()
{

    Line line1(10);

    Line line2 = line1; // This also calls copy constructor

    display(line1);
    display(line2);

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain this output?

I'm not able to understand the repetitive printing.

OUTPUT:

```
//Normal constructor allocating ptr
//Copy constructor allocating ptr.
//Copy constructor allocating ptr.
//Length of line : 10
//Freeing memory!
//Copy constructor allocating ptr.
//Length of line : 10
//Freeing memory!
//Freeing memory!
//Freeing memory!
```

Comment: We have removed the C tag from your two previous questions and now we're removing it from this one. We're not doing it for fun. Don't use irrelevant tags. Your code is CLEARLY not C.

Comment: Very strange code too. Why use the array to store both data and metadata when you have a class? Makes no sense.

Comment: Also, you have not explained what's unclear. What in detail is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of events in you program, divided into small steps for better comprehension, goes like this:

Calls the constructor for `line1`:

```
Line line1(10); //Normal constructor allocating ptr
```

---

**1.** Copies `line1` to `line2` and for that it calls the copy constructor:

```
   Line line2 = line1; //Copy constructor allocating ptr.
```

---

**2.** Because the parameter is passed by value to `display()` it copies `line1` to be use in the function:

```
    display(line1); //Copy constructor allocating ptr.
```

**3.** Then it executes `display()`, after that it no longer needs `line1` parameter which is a copy of `line1` so it calls its destructor:

```
//Length of line : 10
//Freeing memory!
```

---

**4.** Again, it copies `line2` because you pass it to `display()` by value, it would be different if you passed it by pointer or reference:

```
   display(line2); //Copy constructor allocating ptr.
```

**5.** Executes `display` and, again, calls the destructor for the copy made:

```
//Length of line : 10
//Freeing memory!
```

---

**6.** After that it calls destructors for original `line1` and `line2` objects before ending execution:

```
//Freeing memory!
//Freeing memory!
```

---

You can observe the difference if you pass the object by reference, *i.e.*:

```
void display(Line &obj)
```

With the above construct you'll see two less copy constructors and consequently two less destructors:

```
//Normal constructor allocating ptr
//Copy constructor allocating ptr.
//Length of line : 10
//Length of line : 10
//Freeing memory!
//Freeing memory!
```

For this, ideally you would use `void display(const Line &obj)`, since you don't intend to change the object, but then you will need to change `int getLength(void);` to `int getLength(void) const;` given that you will be using a `const` reference.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are confused by the copy when you call display.

```cpp
void display(Line obj) { // creates a copy of the argument
```

Try it with

```cpp
void display(Line const& obj) {  // creates a const reference to the argument
```

And do not forget to make get lenght const

```cpp
int getLength() const;
int Line::getLength() const{
```

So you can call getLenth on a const Line object.

Comment: It still fails. `getLength` needs to be a const function

Comment: so make it const?
I think you should try to google for some time before asking questions.

Comment: consider your language. The comment was not by the OP. I suppose it was an attempt to help improve this answer

Comment: my fault sorry.